# Should I use inheritance in my case?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, inheritance

I have 2 classes that should run a service when calling their `Start` method, but before it they should:

1. Copy items to F folder
2. Open S service in remote server if it's not opened already
3. Run #SN service in remote server

They differ in 1 & 3 steps:

1. In 1st step each one of them may copy different items depending on some parameters
2. In 3rd step each one call different service name

My question is should both of them derive from base class and each one will override 1 & 3 steps OR minor overlap between the two classes is not a reason for inheritance?

I'm more inclined to the second opinion and I think to do `Runner` class that has static methods `RunService1` & `RunService2` and each one will copy items it should copy, open S service and run #S1/#S2 service.

Here is example of separated class and using base class:

**Run1**

```
class Run1
{
    private _src;
    private _dest;
    private _mode;

    public Run1(string src, string dest, int mode, int arg1, int arg2,...)
    {
       _src = src;
       _dest = dest;
       _mode = mode;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        PrepareFolders();

        OpenServer();

        RunInternal();
    }

    private void PrepareFolders()
    {
        // copy from src to dest
        _src = _dest // after the copying the new source is the destination

       // more copying specific folders to dest depending on mode
    }

    private void OpenServer()
    {
       var client = new WcfClient();
       client.OpenServer();
    }

    private void RunInternal()
    {
       var client = new WcfClient();
       client.RunService1(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...);
    }
}
```

**Run2**

```
class Run2
{
    private _src;
    private _dest;
    private _mode;

    public Run2(string src, string dest, int mode)
    {
       _src = src;
       _dest = dest;
       _mode = mode;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        PrepareFolders();

        if(!IfServerOpened())
        {
             OpenServer();
        }

        RunInternal();
    }

    private void PrepareFolders()
    {        
       // This copy the same as in Run1 
        _src = _dest // after the copying the new source is the destination

       // Some other copying specific to Run2

    }

    private void OpenServer()
    {
       var client = new WcfClient();
       client.OpenServer();
    }

    private void RunInternal()
    {
       var client = new WcfClient();
       client.RunService2(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

**With base class:**

```
class Run1 : RunBase { ... }
class Run2 : RunBase { ... }

abstract class RunBase
{
   protected string Source { get; private set; }  

   public RunBase(string src, string dest) { ... }
   protected abstract PrepareFoldersInternal();
   public void Run()
    {
        PrepareFolders();

        if(!IfServerOpened())
        {
             OpenServer();
        }

        RunInternal();
    }

    public void  PrepareFolders()
    {
        // copy from src to dest
        _src = _dest // after the copying the new source is the destination
        Source  = dest;

       PrepareFoldersInternal();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit abstract; would you mind posting the code of those classes? My first guess would be that if it can't be solved purely by passing in different parameters, step 1 (and possibly 3) should be performed by different objects that you pass in as dependencies (also going by the general rule of favoring composition over inheritance). But that would be much easier to say with some actual code.

Comment: @GCATNM, Sorry, that I didn't specified my language and didn't included code. I updated my post and I'll be glad if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the capabilities of your language.

#### Strategies, and higher order functions

If I were to design this, there would only be one class, with a `Start` method, and two properties `service` (which somehow specifies a service), and `selectItems` which is a function that returns a list of items to be copied. These would then be initialized in the constructor. In C#-like pseudocode

```
class Runner {
  private Service service;
  private delegate Items[] selectItems();
  // some constructor here
  public void Start() {
     // do actual stuff here ...
  }
}

var runner1 = new Runner(some_service, awesome_item_selector);
runner1.Start();
```

As the object would only have one method, this is equivalent to using a higher-order function which returns a closure over the two properties. In Go-like pseudocode:

```
func Runner (service Service, selectItems func() []Item) func() {
   return func () {
     // do actual stuff here
   }
}

runner1 := Runner(someService, someSelector)
runner1() // execute it
```

#### Mixin' some traits

If you have a language that supports mixins/traits/roles, you could create a trait `Runner` that requires a `selectItems` method and a `service` property. The trait would then implement a `Start` method that uses those requirements. One would then create two classes `RunService1` and `RunService2` that uses the trait. In Perl/Moose-like Pseudocode:

```
role Runner {
  requires 'selectItems', 'service';
  method Start () {
    # do actual stuff here
  }
}

class RunService1 with Runner {
  has service => (is => 'ro', default => 'some service');
  method selectItems () {
    # return list of items
  }
}

my $run1 = RunService1->new();
$run1->Start();
```

Is this starting to look overengineered? Me too. In fact, this has no advantages  over the previous approach iff your language supports higher order functions or lambdas or function pointers or whatnot.

#### If you are stuck with a braindead language…

… you can fake traits by using abstract classes with the methods `service` and `selectItems` marked as virtual. The default implementation would then throw an error if executed. The child classes would override these methods, and thus suppress the errors.

#### Conclusion:

1. Your first option seems fairly sensible, if your language can't do better
2. Your second solution would create a class that isn't easy to extend, has more than one task/concern, and is just plain procedural programming.
3. Higher-order functions are awesome.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Sorry, that I didn't specified my language and didn't included code. I updated my post and I'll be glad if you could take a look.